# Inserting streaming data into an Amazon Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, spark-streaming, amazon-redshift

I am trying to direct insert sparkstream data into an Amazon Redshift cluster but am not able to find right way.

Below is the code that i got but its first inserting into S3 then copying to Redshift:.

```
#REDSHIFT_JDBC_URL = "jdbc:redshift://%s:5439/%s" % (REDSHIFT_SERVER, DATABASE)

df.write \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", REDSHIFT_JDBC_URL) \
    .option("dbtable", TABLE_NAME) \
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://%s:%s@%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, SECRET, S3_BUCKET_PATH)) \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

Does it impact streaming or insertion performance?

Or any other way to do it?

Comment: what is the source of your streaming data? are you using spark?

Comment: Source is kafka .Use case is to get the data from source and process the data & insert it into redshiftdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redshift data source for Spark that you are using writes data to Redshift by writing the data to a temporary file on S3 then uses the Redshift COPY command to load the data into Redshift. The COPY command requires the data to be in a file on S3, this is to most efficient way to load data into Redshift so what your code is currently doing appears to be correct.

See also: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/19/introducing-redshift-data-source-for-spark.html

Comment: Yes,Do you think ,Is there any other way to insert data into Redshift via spark streaming?

Comment: The only other way would be to use SQL INSERT statements somehow, but for anything other than trivial amounts of data that is going to be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Redshift now support streaming insert natively through Kinesis Data Streams. No need of intermediate S3 staging. Feature is now in public preview

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/02/amazon-redshift-public-preview-streaming-ingestion-kinesis-data-streams/